# Rspec controller test failing when nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Rails 3.2.6

I've set up a Contact Controller and form as suggested by this article:
http://matharvard.ca/posts/2011/aug/22/contact-form-in-rails-3/

My `Message` model class:

```
class Message
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :message_body

  # validations are here...

  def initialize(attributes = {})
      attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
      end
  end

  def persisted?
      false
  end
end
```

The `Contact Controller`:

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
        ContactMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
        redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
        render :new
    end
end
```

My rspec controller test:

```
describe "POST create" do
    context "with valid information" do
      let (:message) { FactoryGirl.build(:message) }
      it "creates a new message" do
        post :create, params: message
        assigns(:message).should eq(message)
    end
  end
end
```

I've verified the `message` variable via `let` is not nil, so FactoryGirl is doing its job.

The test result:

```
ContactController POST create with valid information creates a new message
 Failure/Error: post :create, params: message
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
 # ./app/models/message.rb:14:in `initialize'
 # ./app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:8:in `new'
 # ./app/controllers/contact_controller.rb:8:in `create'
 # ./spec/controllers/contact_controller_spec.rb:22:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I know it's failing because of `Message`'s `initialize` method.  But I'm now sure why it's initializing nil.  It appears to work fine when I test the form in the development environment.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You seem to be missing an `end` from your `it` block.

Comment: A typo when I pasted code over into StackOverflow which is now corrected.

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the value of params[:message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass a hash as the value to `post`'s hash option.  Like so:

```
message_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)
post :create, message: message_attributes
```

In order to compare the two messages in the test, I had to modify the `Message` model like so:

```
attr_accessor :attributes, :name, :email, :message_body
def initialize(attributes = {})
    if not attributes.nil?
        attributes.each do |name, value|
            send("#{name}=", value)
        end
    end
    @attributes = attributes
end
```

So the final passing test looked like this:

```
it "creates a new message" do
    message_attributes = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:message)
    post :create, message: message_attributes
    assigns(:message).attributes.symbolize_keys.should eq(message_attributes)
end
```

I'm not sure if this was the best solution, but it does create a passing test and verifies that the controller is creating a message correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the message with explicit name of it, like this:

```
it "creates a new message" do
    post :create, :message => message
    assigns(:message).should eq(message)
end
```

or the short style:

```
post :create, message: message
```

So then you will have a key `'message'` in params hash

```
params[:message] = ... # here's your message
```

Otherwise you'll not have a key in `params` and hense the `params[:message]` returns nil

Comment: This still didn't work for me.  The @message is created without any attributes when I try it with this method.